# Why do i get “ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE” after client certificate authentication?

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate

I created an API (in python) and I wish to share it with my coworkers. I created a docker container on which the API is running and I use nginx to secure the inconming requests.
For SSL/TLS I use a self signed certificate for now. And for authentication I specified in nginx to require a client certificate. I then started the docker container on a GCP compute engine instance. I'm certain the firewall rules for the instance are OK because everything works fine if I disable the client authentication setting. My coworkers are able to access the API without problems.

The problem starts when I turn on client authentication. Me and two coworkers installed our client certificates. I can access the website without problem, same as coworker 1, after selecting the client certificate. Coworker 2 gets a response that asks for a certificate, he selects his certificate and then he gets ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE (on google chrome, edge, postman, ...), every time. If he doesn't select a certificate he gets the standard

> 400 Bad Request
>
> No required SSL certificate was sent
>
> nginx/1.14.2

which is expected.

But what can be causing the ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE? The authentication itsself seems to work.

The relevant nginx code:

```
    server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name 0.0.0.0;
    keepalive_timeout   70;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/api-server-cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/api-server.pem;
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/CA-cert.pem;
    ssl_verify_client on;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000/;
        proxy_set_header Host      $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_buffer_size   128k;
        proxy_buffers   4 256k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;

    }

    client_max_body_size 5M;

}
```

Comment: Please see the error log of your server. Also, `http://0.0.0.0:5000/` is not a correct target address  (and this might be the cause of the problem) - to access a local application use `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I should delete this question or answer it myself.
Apparently it's not a server side issue. Some anti-virus softwares will block websites with untrusted certificates without warning. So adding the url/ip address to the anti-virus whitelist solves the issue.